# Can you click to select with FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar and I want to allow my users to select a range.  Unfortunately, the click and drag is confusing for a lot of users so I want to offer the click on two separate dates to select a range. How do I configure FullCalendar to have the click two separate dates to select a range feature similar to this?

http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/daterangepicker-drp--default

Comment: You can't, as far as I know. Selecting is done by either clicking on a single time (and therefore selecting a time period with the default duration), or dragging. Perhaps you could [request a feature](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) - or even contribute the necessary code yourself towards your suggested alternative method.

Comment: Having said that, you _might_ be able to do something by handling a single click on "select", making it select 0 minutes, remembering the selected start time in a separate variable, and then indicating to the user they should click again, and using the next time "select" is handled to combine the remembered start time with the newly-selected "start" time - but using that second time as the "end" time and running the .select() function to cause a different selection to be made. Just an idea, I don't know if it will work - give it a try.